# IE and Chrome inline-block css different behavior

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a code where `#page_field` is parent and have two children. So, I want these two blocks go one after another. What I faced is that chrome display `left_block` correctly: `pager_separator_design` is `30px` wide, so `30px` + `120px` (relative left) give me `150px` and this is what should be done.
However IE, do not add `width` of `pager_separator_design` so total left 120 is wrong. Firefox do like Chrome.
What can I do?
**HTML**

```
<div id="page_field"> 
    <div id="pager_separator_design"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="left_block">
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page_field
{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left:0px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height:auto;
    display: table;
}

#pager_separator_design
{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 120px;
    background-image: url('separator_new.png'); 
    width:30px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}
#left_block
{   
    vertical-align: top; 
    position:relative;
    left:120px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:850px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

I am using IE10.

Comment: Whenever you post a question based on IE please tell which version it is and also provide a HTML code or probably http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Good advice. Version 10.

<div id="page_field">
  <div id="pager_separator_design">
  </div>
  <div id="left_block"></div>
</div>

Comment: are you using a [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

Display inline-block has a margin issue when trying to align elements horizontally. I think it's about 6px that shouldn't be there (usually in IE).

Try adding `margin: 0 0 0 -6px` to your elements to see if that solves the issue.

Caveat: Not sure if I fully understood the issue, so this is a bit of a guess.

Comment: No, it do not work. I add, <!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme-ie.css">
<![endif]-->, and it solved partly the problem, but do you have other good solution?

Comment: I'd need to see more code, this is just guess work. Put an example up on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Tigran This jsfiddle is *much* different from your question. If the question has all the relevant parts to show your problem, then create a jsfiddle with just that. If the whole jsfiddle is necessary to show the problem, then please adjust the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, today, I found a solution and the problem:
I used table, table-row and table-cell. + added addtional emply cell at the left.
And problem was that I made IE show sites like IE 7. I did it many weeks ago and forget to tur n it off.
My css:

```
 #page_field
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: table;
    position:relative;
}
#middle
{
    display:table-row;
}
#left_block
{
    width:120px;
    display: table-cell;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#pager_separator_design
{
    position:relative;
    display: table-cell;
    background-image: url('separator_new.png'); 
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    width:30px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:10;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#right_block
{   
    vertical-align: top; 
    position:relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width:850px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

And code is:

```
<div id="page_field">
    <div class="middle">
        <div id="left_block">
        </div>
        <div id="pager_separator_design">
        </div>
        <div id="right_block">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will help somebody.